# Issue with List.Add(): it only displays the last row

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Issue with List.Add(): it only saves the last added item, it binds the last data repeatedly, please someone help me to clear it. I am trying out in mvc 4 as Begineer. I am also struggling with basic of mvc 4. thank u in advance.

```
var modelList = new List<MyCourseData>();
string batchid = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["batchid"];
SqlConnection con = null;
string result = "";
DataSet ds = null;
con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ToString());
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from [Student].[dbo].[tbl_batch] where batchid=@batchid", con);
//cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@batchid", batchid);
con.Open();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
con.Close();
for (int i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    var model = new MyCourseData();                  
    var classdates = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["class_dates"].ToString();
    int j = 0;
    // string[] parts = classdates.Split(',');
    foreach (string CourseDates in classdates.Split(','))
    {
         model.batchid = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["batchid"].ToString();
         model.course = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["course"].ToString();
         model.trainer = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["trainer"].ToString();
         model.class_dates = CourseDates;
         modelList.Add(model);

    }

}
return modelList;
```

Comment: Learn to dispose your stuff, like connections and commands. Start using `using`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because you are adding the same instance of MyCourseData in the list with value changing in every iteration. 
You need to create new instance of MyCourseData for every iteration,

```
var modelList = new List<MyCourseData>();
string batchid = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["batchid"];
SqlConnection con = null;
string result = "";
DataSet ds = null;
con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ToString());
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from [Student].[dbo].[tbl_batch] where batchid=@batchid", con);
//cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@batchid", batchid);
con.Open();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
con.Close();
for (int i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{

    var classdates = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["class_dates"].ToString();
    int j = 0;
   // string[] parts = classdates.Split(',');
     foreach (string CourseDates in classdates.Split(','))
     {
        var model = new MyCourseData();                  
        model.batchid = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["batchid"].ToString();
        model.course = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["course"].ToString();
        model.trainer = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["trainer"].ToString();
        model.class_dates = CourseDates;

        modelList.Add(model);

     }

}
return modelList;
}
```